# Cardinality problem with multiple sets

Tags: proof-writing

What we are given in part A) This is part B)

[image: Whats given]

What we are asked to prove
[image: What to Prove]

My best idea is that if you evaluate what the proof is, it turns into what is given except A is Ai and B is Ai+1 and all the way to An. On the other side, its just |A||Ai+1|...|An|. So they are the same thing I can just expand the proof and use the given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. You'll want to use induction, and you have the base case $|A_1|=|A_1|$. Now you just need to make the inductive step using what you are given.

Comment: Thanks! Ill try that out, good idea.

Comment: The base case it trivial. What is given is to be used as a part of the induction step.